# Colon operator in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, codec

I'm trying to implement a decoder for a codec, and while reading the whitepaper I stumbled across this

```
Variable > 96000 ? 4 : 2;
```

what does the question mark `?` and the colon `:` between those two numbers do?

I've never seen this before (although I am a noob), and google isn't much help.

Comment: Search for "`ternary operator in C`" on Google.

Comment: If Variable is larger than 96000, the result is 4. Otherwise 2.

Comment: Was searching Google too much of a pain in the ass?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: how would you find this in Google if you didn't know it was called "ternary operator"?

Comment: @Eduardo [Easy if you think about it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mE3ehB9jpts).

Comment: basic true false if statement with 4 being result if true and 2 being result if false. Very simple don't see how you couldn't find it. Some links - http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/operators/ternary-operator.html , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F: , http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4213hs1.aspx, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_conditional_operator.htm - **first four search results on google**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does '?' do in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795286/what-does-do-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

This is ternary operator, this works like if else condition.

```
Variable > 96000 ? 4 : 2;
```

In this line if `Variable > 96000` is true it will return `4` else it will return `2`

A traditional if-else construct in C

```
if (a > b) {
    result = x;
} else {
    result = y;
}
```

This can be rewritten as the following statement:

```
result = a > b ? x : y;
```

Answer (score 1):

`?:` is the conditional operator in C.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3A

http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx4eb.html

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged because if the link becomes old or invalid the response fails to help anyone.

Comment: It not a link only answer, it gives the name of the operator which should be enough for OP to google it.

Answer (score 0):

```
return ( Variable > 96000 ) ? 4 : 2;
```

translates to

```
if(Variable > 96000){

    return 4;
}else {
    return 2;
}
```

you are probably missing a return in the front of your statement.

Comment: not necessarily to miss a return, you can have `int a = x>0 ? x: -x;`

Answer (score 0):

This is basically an equivalence statement in C , the following example will elaborate its use.
In the example below, two numbers are compared and the larger number is returned.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int get_larger(int a, int b)
{
return (a > b) ? a : b; // if a is greater than b, return a, else return b
}

int main ()
{
  int a = 100;
  int b = 101;
  printf("Larger Number = %d\n", get_larger(a,b));
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its ternary operator that is equivalent to If else condition in C/C++.

## NOTE:

Its recommended to use parenthesis while using this operator to avoid side-effects of operator precedence problems as mentioned in [Unexpected Result, Ternary Operator in Gnu C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763483/unexpected-result-ternary-operator-in-gnu-c)