# C How to identify rvalue and lvalue?

Tags: c, lvalue, rvalue

In C, is there a way to identify the rvalues and lvalues ?

Some of them are easy to identity say, in an assignment, the left value is lvalue and the value in the right is rvalue.

But other scenarios, identification with such a rule is difficult.

For example : `*p++`  and `i++` (where p is a pointer to integer and i is an integer) - how to identify whether it is an rvalue or lvalue ? 
The context is `++*p++` works while `++i++` does not since `i++` is an rvalue (as told by serious guys).

How to identify rvalue and lvalue in an expression?

Comment: I think this is a good question but what do you mean by "identify"?  Do you want a comprehensive list of operations and whether they return l or r values?  A way to tell from a function sig?  A way to see each line of code that has an lvalue or rvalue in it?

Comment: @djechlin, By 'identify' I mean, whether I can determine whether a code fragment  works by reviewing a source code (without need for compliation). Without a comprehensive list, is there is method that I can apply to identify rvalue and lvalue ? But if there is a comprehensive list exists, that would work for me.

Comment: I think you should start by forgetting "rvalue = value on the right", it is just plain wrong.

Comment: @qdii, I agree. But how to identify what is right ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [lvalue and rvalue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038414/lvalue-and-rvalue)

Comment: @Bo Persson, with the selected answer for that link, I could not identify whether *p++ is an rvalue or lavlue. *p++ looks like an rvalue as per that answer, but that is an lvalue which is why ++*p++ works (at least I think so)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*lvalue* (from *left-hand side (LHS) value*) in something that refers to a memory (or register) storage and that you can assign values to. `*p++` is an *lvalue* since it is a dereferenced pointer (i.e. refers to the location in memory that `ptr` points to while the value of `ptr` itself is the address of that location) and `++*ptr++` actually means: `*ptr = *ptr + 1; ptr = ptr + 1;` - it increments the value pointed to by `ptr` and then increments the pointer value itself. `i++` is not an *lvalue* since it is the value of `i` incremented by 1 and does not refer to a location in memory. You can think of such values as final - they cannot be further modified and can only be used as values to assign to *lvalues*. That's why they are called *rvalues* (from *right-hand side (RHS) value*).

LHS and RHS refer to both sides of the assignment expression `A = B;`. `A` is the LHS and `B` is the RHS.

Answer (score 3):

The term *lvalue* has been with C (and was carried forward to C++ and expanded later on). There was no *rvalue* to begin with. The draft I have (N1570) does list two occurrences of the term *rvalue* -- oncee in footnote #64 and once in the index.

In a nutshell: In the C world you have two types of objects -- *lvalues* and everything else.

Note that footnotes are not part of the standard but they can provide some helpful insights. Here goes footnote 64:

> 64) The name ‘‘lvalue’’ comes originally from the assignment expression E1 = E2, in which the left
>   operand E1 is required to be a (modifiable) lvalue. It is perhaps better considered as representing an
>   object ‘‘locator value’’. What is sometimes called ‘‘rvalue’’ is in this International Standard described
>   as the ‘‘value of an expression’’.
>
> An obvious example of an lvalue is an identifier of an object. As a further example, if E is a unary
>   expression that is a pointer to an object, *E is an lvalue that designates the object to which E points.

This gives a good start. Now, bear in mind that an expression is built up from objects (and operators but we'll get there in a bit), and there are two fundamental things that you need to worry about when dealing with objects: Type and Value. Let's see what does the standard say about the type restrictions then (6.3.2.1/p1):

> An lvalue is an expression (with an object type other than void) that potentially
>   designates an object;64) if an lvalue does not designate an object when it is evaluated, the behavior is undefined.

Also, note the next line which is important:

> When an object is said to have a particular type, the type is
>   specified by the lvalue used to designate the object.

So, an *lvalue* can be used as a substitute for the type (we'll see this too). Next, let us take a look at the contexts where an object *is* an *lvalue* (6.3.2.1/2):

> when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, the
>   unary & operator, the ++ operator, the -- operator, or the left operand of the . operator
>   or an assignment operator

So, these are the operators that you need to keep an eye out for. In all other cases:

> an lvalue that does not have array type is converted to the
>   value stored in the designated object (and is no longer an lvalue); this is called lvalue
>   conversion.

There are two special types: arrays and function designators. These *decay* i.e. are *converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points
to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue* / *"pointer to function returning type"*. (Remember, we had paused on the fact that *lvalues* can work as types -- this is exactly what they do with `sizeof` and `_Alignof`!)

Answer (score 0):

From Deitel and Deitel:

Variable names are said to be *lvalues* (for "left values") because they can be used on the left side of an assignment operator. Constants are said to be *rvalues* (for "right values") because they can be used on only the right side of an assignment operator. Note that *lvalues* can also be used as *rvalues*, but not vice versa.

```
x = 3;  /*  here, x is an lvalue */
c = x;  /*  and in the next line it is an rvalue */
```

Comment: Sounds like he knew that and wants to know more comprehensive ways to identify them.