# what are l-value and r-value expression?

Tags: c, lvalue, rvalue

what is the order of precedence for pre ++, post ++ and * ? how these expression are parsed in VS 08 compiler.

```
 void main(){
        int arr[] ={34,11,43};
        int *ptr = arr;
        printf("%d",++*ptr++);
        printf("%d",++ptr++);
 }
```

explain the l value expression. i want to understand why ++*ptr++ is a valid expression, while ++ptr++ is giving error.

```
error: '++' needs l-value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
++p++
```

Says: pre-increment `p` and post-increment `p` (in unspecified order).  Even if it were allowed it would invoke undefined behavior due to [modifying `p` more than once before encountering a sequence point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points).

Anyway, the increment operators, post- and pre-, return an [rvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038414/lvalue-and-rvalue).  An rvalue is the value of an expression.  It has no location to write to and can be thought as an intermediate value.

```
*p++
```

This expression initially results in an lvalue,  `*p`. That location can be written to, so it is incremented by the pre-increment and then `p` itself is incremented.  The increment results in an rvalue, but you are not attempting to modify it.

Comment: i want to understand why ++*p++ is valid and ++p++ is not valid

Comment: "++p++ Says: pre-increment p and post-increment p (in unspecified order)" -- this is wrong. See Matt McNabb's answer. "This expression initially results in an rvalue, *p" -- `*p` is an lvalue. "then p itself is incremented. The increment returns an rvalue" -- this is nonsensical; the increment is a side-effect, it doesn't "return" anything, and might not occur until the sequence point.

Comment: Further: "This expression initially results in an rvalue, *p" -- no, it results in the content of `*p`, which is passed to `printf`. Expressions and the values they yield are different things.

Answer (score 3):

The precedence is `++(*(ptr++))` and `++(ptr++)` respectively.

`ptr++` is an rvalue, because the language definition says so. (*rvalue* means that you can use the value but you cannot attempt to refer to the memory location where this value might be stored).

The `++` operator updates the value stored in a memory location, therefore it can only be applied to an lvalue. So `++(ptr++)` is a constraint violation.

However, `*` can be applied to rvalues and the result is an lvalue (i.e. an expression that designates a memory location). So `++` can be applied to `*ptr++` .

Comment: ptr+1 is also an rvalue "because the language definition says so" but there's more to it than that ... an expression that isn't a dereference doesn't make sense as a target for a value.

Comment: what does this statement print?--> printf("%d",++*ptr++); 35 or 12 ?

Comment: @piyukr work out what you think it should print, then try it and see

Answer (score 0):

In C programming preincrement and predecrement operators return an rvalue which essentially tells you that it is a result and not a place to make an assignment. In C++ programming the preincrement and predecrement operators return an lvalue where you can perform further assignments.

A statement like,

```
int i=10;
++i=5;
```

is syntactiacally valid in C++. But in C it is a syntax error.

Even in C++ the postincrement and postdecrement operators return an rvalue. Thus the following statement will give you a syntax error in both C and C++.

```
int i=10;
i++=5;
```

Comment: "++i=5; is syntactiacally valid in C++" -- but is pointless since the `++` is superseded by the `=`, resulting in `i` being 5.