# Function with parameter type that has a copy-constructor with non-const ref chosen?

Tags: c++, rvalue, overload-resolution, const-reference

Some time ago I was confused by the following behavior of some code when I wanted to write a `is_callable<F, Args...>` trait. Overload resolution won't call functions accepting arguments by non-const ref, right? Why doesn't it reject in the following because the constructor wants a `Test&`? I expected it to take `f(int)`!

```
struct Test {
  Test() { }

  // I want Test not be copyable from rvalues!
  Test(Test&) { }

  // But it's convertible to int
  operator int() { return 0; }
};

void f(int) { }
void f(Test) { }

struct WorksFine { };
struct Slurper { Slurper(WorksFine&) { } };
struct Eater { Eater(WorksFine) { } };

void g(Slurper) { }
void g(Eater) { } // chooses this, as expected

int main() {
  // Error, why?
  f(Test());

  // But this works, why?
  g(WorksFine());
}
```

Error message is

```
m.cpp: In function 'int main()':
m.cpp:33:11: error: no matching function for call to 'Test::Test(Test)'
m.cpp:5:3: note: candidates are: Test::Test(Test&)
m.cpp:2:3: note:                 Test::Test()
m.cpp:33:11: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'void f(Test)'
```

Can you please explain why one works but the other doesn't?

Comment: It compiles just fine on my MSVC++ 10 Complier.

Comment: Okay... I understand.. "Fehler" means "Error".."Anmerkung" means "Note"..haha..learning new human language...which language is this by the way? :|

Comment: @Nawaz oops, I forgot to translate!

Comment: @Johannes : hehe..no problems...i just compiled it with gcc, and I got the translation :P.. and there is google also...

Comment: Just a shot in the blue, does it make a difference if you mark `operator int()` as `const`?

Comment: @Dave18 only solutions containing reasons beyond "my compiler accepts it" are accepted as answer to the puzzle.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub: What if the correct reason is: "Your compiler is wrong for the reasons stated in the question."?

Comment: I feel that this topic is somehow related to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704404/implicit-conversion-const-reference-vs-non-const-reference-vs-non-reference

Comment: @Charles it wouldn't be a sufficient reason for me to accept it, lol.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub: I don't really undestand what you are asking for, then.

Comment: Note that Comeau fails with the same error.

Comment: @Charles i'm for some confirmation for or against the suspicion I had. It can't be given simply by repeating my suspicion. Here we would have my suspicion, your suspicion (?) and MSVC++ against gcc/clang and comeau. I can't see a clear winner.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub: Forget what I said, I totally misread the question!

Comment: The title of this question is misleading. It's not `Test(Test&)` that is chosen by any overload resolution, it's one of the two `f` which is chosen by overload resolution. The question is which one and why.

Comment: @Charles I wanted to make it sound like a "real" question, not giving the answer right away. I think you are right, it rather introduces more confusion than question-ness, so since we have a good answer anyway now, I will change the title!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overload resolution picks the function that is the closest match to the supplied argument.  You supplied a Test.  No conversion necessary -- identity conversion used.  Thus function resolution chooses f(Test).  Test can't be copied from rvalue, which you supplied, but overload resolution has succeeded already...conversion to int is never checked.

`g(Eater)` is chosen because the types don't exactly match, the identity conversion is NOT used, and the compiler has to find a conversion routine that works.  `g(Slurper)` doesn't because you can't make one out of the supplied argument.

"Why doesn't this one fail: `struct A { operator int(); }; void f(A&); void f(int); void g() { f(A()); }`"

Because f(A&) is not a viable overload for the supplied argument.  In this case the parameter is a reference and the fact that temps don't bind to non-const is allowed to effect the resolution.  In this case it does and the that version of the function becomes a non-candidate, leaving only the one and it works.

Comment: Why doesn't this one fail: `struct A { operator int(); }; void f(A&); void f(int); void g() { f(A()); }` and why does it work for my other test? Why is it better to convert `WorksFine` to `Eater` than to `Slurper`?

Comment: @Noah: It's confusing to me that if `Test` can't be copied from rvalue, then how could one say that overload resolution has succeeded? :-/

Comment: If a parameter has reference type, though, the conversion sequence includes binding the reference. The fact that a reference to non-`const` cannot be bound to an rvalue _should_ affect whether the candidate function is actually viable.

Comment: @Nawaz - it is a little unintuitive I guess but by my interpretation, since one of the available versions of f has a parameter type exactly matching the type of the expression fed to it, no test is ever done to see if you can actually call that function, constructing a copy of the supplied argument, etc...  I don't even think the reference rules apply (which I believe end up saying the same thing because of the "binds directly" stuff) because the text is talking about the type of the parameter, not the argument.

Comment: @Charles there is actually a paragraph explicitly stating this matter such that clang/gcc/comeau are right. But it's kinda hidden!

Comment: @Charles - it doesn't in this case.  f takes a non-reference as parameter.  Remember that 'parameter' is explicitly defined as standard speak for the type the function expects (that which is in the definition).

Comment: @NoahRoberts: Oops, I completely misread the questions. Thanks!

Comment: @Noah I will do fairplay and accept your answer. Your sayings are correct because it's what 13.3.3.1.2p4 says.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub: What about 13.3.3.1p6 and 13.3.3.1p8? I don't think you should even get into a section about "User-defined conversion sequences".

Comment: @Charles - yeah, p6/p8 does it in by my interpretation too.  There's also a single, solitary (from what I could tell) comment about the "identity conversion" in parentheses in 13.3.3.1.1p2 "(that is, no conversion)".  It's the only place I could find it remotely defined to be sure it wasn't defined as calling the copy constructor.

Comment: @Charles oh indeed. 13.3.3.1p6 looks like a better paragraph to cite than my 13.3.3.1.2p4. Not only better, but I think it's *the* paragraph to cite here, since 13.3.3.1.2p4 doesn't say what exact conversion is used. I stand corrected :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, for overload resolution, it is assumed that an object of type A can be converted to an object of type A regardless of any cv-qualification on either of the two.

From draft n1905:

**13.3.3.1: Overloading.Overload Resolution.Best Viable Function.Implicit Conversion Sequences**

> 6 **When the parameter type is not a reference**, the implicit conversion sequence models a copy-initialization of the parameter from the argument expression.  The implicit conversion sequence is the one required to convert the argument
>   expression to an rvalue of the type of the parameter. [ *Note*: when the parameter has a class type, this is a conceptual
>   conversion defined for the purposes of clause 13; the actual initialization is defined in terms of constructors and is not
>   a conversion.  — *end note* ] **Any difference in top-level cv-qualification is subsumed by the initialization itself and does
>   not constitute a conversion.**  [ *Example*: a parameter of type A can be initialized from an argument of type const  A.
>   The implicit conversion sequence for that case is the identity sequence; it contains no “conversion” from const  A to
>   A.  — *end example* ] **When the parameter has a class type and the argument expression has the same type, the implicit
>   conversion sequence is an identity conversion**. [...]