# When is an array automatically initialized to it's default datatype?

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

When does the compiler auto initialize the arrays to it's default datatype?

I know that in this example the arrays will be initialized, except the fact that i was expecting ([reading here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707942/default-values-in-array)) `\0` value for char instead in my console there were `spaces` (at least this is what i think because there is nothing).

```
#define MAX_LENGTH 25

// Array global
int vector[MAX_LENGTH];
char vector_char[MAX_LENGTH];

int main()
{
    //Print int array
    for(int i = 0;i < MAX_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        cout << vector[i] << " ";                        // All outputs 0
    }
    cout << endl;

    //Print char array and output text to see that there is 
    //Something printed
    cout << "start";
    for(int i = 0;i < MAX_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        cout << vector_char[i] << " ";                     //All outputs...
    }
    cout <<"end"<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Other two situations that I've encountered is when an array is internal to a function (where the values will be "garbage" or "impredictibile" E.g:

```
int main()
{
    int internal_vector[MAX_LENGTH];

    for(int i = 0;i < MAX_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        cout << internal_vector[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and another one when the array is a member of a class (if you try anything you will have the surprise that array will contain garbage values:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    int array[100];
...
}
```

---

So, when is an array automatically initialized to it's default datatype and when should i make my own function to initialize each element?

Comment: Wow: "int vector[MAX_LENGTH];
char vector_char[MAX_LENGTH];"  Please do not use plain C-Style arrays in C++. Never. Use ````std::vector```` or other STL container. You even name your C-Style arrays like this . . .

Comment: What exactly led you to believe that `char c=0; std::cout << c` will produce "\0" as the output? This is not true. Your char vector is also zero-initialized, but the char 0 is simply not shown, so all you see are spaces.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik i though that the char default value it is `\0` therefore declaring it outside any function this would be the value

Comment: @ArminMontigny a link for me to better understand what are you talking about would help me

Comment: I was very clear in my comment. Read it again. If you inspect your `char` vector's value in a debugger, you will be surprised to learn that they are, indeed, `\0`s. What you're missing is that a `\0` character will output two characters, a backslash and a digit 0, to `std::cout`. Wherever you read that from, that source was incorrect.

Comment: If I remember correctly an array (or to be precise a C-style array) is default initialized exactly if it has static storage duration, i.e. if it is declared at namespace scope or with the identifier `static`.  The character `\0` is the interpretation of the `char` with value `0`. `\0` is an escape sequence for this character, since it has no printable representation, it has no width.

Comment: Regarding @ArminMontigny comment: The C++-way to use an array with compile-time size is [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) which is basically a wrapper around a C-style array. It has the advantages, that it knows its own size, you can use `.at()` to index with bounds checking and it does not decay to a pointer. All of this with basically no overhead at runtime. [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is the C++ way to use dynamic arrays, it can even change its size during runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global objects have [static storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration), they will be [zero-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) from the beginning,

> For every named variable with static or thread-local storage duration `that is not subject to constant initialization (since C++14)`, before any other initialization.
>
> If T is a scalar type, the object's initial value is the integral constant zero explicitly converted to T.
>
> If T is array type, each element is zero-initialized

That means all the elements of `vector` will be initialized to `0`, all the elements of `vector_char` will be initialized to `'\0'`.

On the other hand, all the elements of `internal_vector` will be initialized to indeterminate values in [default initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization).

> if T is an array type, every element of the array is default-initialized;
>
> otherwise, nothing is done: the objects with automatic storage duration (and their subobjects) are initialized to indeterminate values.
>
> Default initialization of non-class variables with automatic and dynamic storage duration produces objects with indeterminate values (static and thread-local objects get [zero initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization))

Note that it's a little complex for `array`, whose storage duration depends on how the instance is declared.

Comment: what storage duration have a member of a class?

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu It depends on the object. Answer revised.