# Where/how are the arithmetic operators for atomic< T > defined?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

The standard arithmetic operators, such as `*` and `+`, work as expected on classes like `atomic< int >`. However, I can't find any definition of them in the `<atomic>` header file and no reference to them in the standard.

Are they defined implicitly somewhere or am I just looking in the wrong place?

For example, where is the multiplication function called in the following code defined?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    atomic< int > i( 42 );
    atomic< float > f( 6.66 );

    cout << i * f;
    //cout << operator*( i, f); //error: ‘operator*’ not defined

    return 0;
}
```

For anyone else reading this question there is a nice discussion of what is going on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128908/c-type-conversion-faq).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `atomic` types have a conversion `operator T` that reads atomically - in your `i * f` expression they're both read atomically, thereafter the extracted values - held in CPU registers - are of plain `int` and `float` types and multiplied as per any other pair of `int` and `float`, with the result provided to `operator<<`'s `float` overload.

Keep in mind that the whole idea of atomicity is about loading and storing values from memory in such a way that readers don't see half-written values, and writers don't overlap leaving some hybrid of two values in memory.  Once an atomic value is loaded into a register for some actual use in an expression, or say as a function parameter, it's not accessible to other threads or updated by their writes to the original atomic variable.

Comment: Thanks, I'd never come across these `operator T()` functions before. Do they have a technical name? I'd like to look them up in the standard.

Comment: @andrew.punnett You're welcome.  You want "conversion functions" - see 12.3 and 12.3.2.  Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, I guess they very similar to an overloaded C-style cast function.

Comment: @andrew.punnett: they're closely related concepts, albeit kind of the other end of the process... this grants the ability to cast from a custom object *to* a specific type, while if you did a C-style cast the the casted-to type would need a constructor *from* this type, which is never possible for a builtin-type.  That is, a user-defined type can't be cast to e.g. `double` unless it provides an `operator double()` or e.g. `operator T` for some type `T` that can undergo a Standard Conversion to `double`.

Answer (score 1):

`atomic<T>` provides `operator T()`. Then built-in operators are happily applied to underlying fundamental types.