# Strange assignment / multiplication operator behaviour in C++

Tags: c++, variable-assignment, operator-keyword, multiplication

Could somebody please explain me wth is wrong with my operators:

```
Matrix3D Matrix3D::operator*(Matrix3D& m) {
    Matrix3D ret;
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++) {
            ret._data[i][j]=0.0;
            for(int k=0;k<4;k++) {
                ret._data[i][j] += (this->_data[i][k]*m._data[k][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

Matrix3D& Matrix3D::operator=(Matrix3D& m) {
    if(this==&m) {
        return *this;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++) {
            this->_data[i][j] = m._data[i][j];
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

Matrix3D Matrix3D::Rotation(double ax, double ay, double az) {
    Matrix3D rotX;
    Matrix3D rotY;
    Matrix3D rotZ;
    rotX(
        1,          0,          0,          0,
        0,          cos(ax),    -sin(ax),   0,
        0,          sin(ax),    cos(ax),    0,
        0,          0,          0,          1
    );
    rotY(
        cos(ay),    0,          sin(ay),    0,
        0,          1,          0,          0,
        -sin(ay),   0,          cos(ay),    0,
        0,          0,          0,          1
    );
    rotZ(
        cos(az),    -sin(az),   0,          0,
        sin(az),    cos(az),    0,          0,
        0,          0,          1,          0,
        0,          0,          0,          1
    );

    // Matrix3D ret;
    // ret = rotX*rotY*rotZ;
    // This doesn't work
    // C:\(...)\Matrix3D.cpp|100|error: no match for 'operator=' in 'ret = Matrix3D::operator*(Matrix3D&)(((Matrix3D&)(& rotZ)))'|

    // however this does work

    Matrix3D ret = rotX*rotY*rotZ;
    return ret;
}
```

as stated in the code above, something like

```
    Matrix3D ret;
    ret = rotX*rotY*rotZ;
```

will result in

```
    C:\(...)\Matrix3D.cpp|100|error: no match for 'operator=' in 'ret = Matrix3D::operator*(Matrix3D&)(((Matrix3D&)(& rotZ)))'|
```

compilation error, while something like

```
    Matrix3D ret = rotX*rotY*rotZ;
```

will compile without any warning or error whatsoever (don't know if the matrixes are right tho, haven't checked that yet...).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, both operators are declared wrongly. They should take a `const` reference to allow rvalues be accepted.

```
Matrix3D Matrix3D::operator*(const Matrix3D& m) const
//                           ^^^^^              ^^^^^
//                                              this too, since you're not
//                                              changing the LHS during '*'.

Matrix3D& Matrix3D::operator=(const Matrix3D& m)
//                            ^^^^^
```

You'll see that `*` doesn't work with `rotX*(rotY*rotZ)`.

The reason `Matrix3D ret = rotX*rotY*rotZ;` compiles is because the `operator=` is not invoked at all. It just calls the copy constructor of Matrix3D to the result of the multiplication. And the multiplication works because `rotX * rotY * rotZ` is rewritten to

```
rotX.operator*(rotY).operator*(rotZ)
```

and `rotY` and `rotZ` are both lvalues, so they can be bound to `Matrix3D&`.

Comment: @user1102495: Are you sure it "worked"?  Did you check if its values were correct?

Comment: Well, why it compiled, I didn't checked the values and after that explanation I assumed that they would be wrong anyway.

Answer (score 5):

### Proper declarations of both `operator*` and `operator=`:

```
Matrix3D  Matrix3D::operator* (Matrix3D const& m) const;
Matrix3D& Matrix3D::operator= (Matrix3D const& m);
```

---

### Reading material:

- [What is lvalue/rvalue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579421/often-used-seldom-defined-terms-lvalue)
- [What is const-correctness, why should ::operator* be const?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html)

---

Your `operator=` accepts a `Matrix3D&` though `rotX*rotY*rotX` will result in an *rvalue* and therefor you cannot bind a reference to it.

To make work your `operator=` should accept a `Matrix3D const&`, which can be bound to both *lvalues* and *rvalues*.

Even though it may look like `Obj a = b` uses `Obj::operator=` it's not, it'll use what is normally referred to as the *copy-constructor*. Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278625/when-do-we-have-to-use-copy-constructors).

Answer (score 4):

Change the signature of the assignment operator to be const-correct:

```
Matrix3D& Matrix3D::operator=(Matrix3D const & m)
//                                     ^^^^^
```

In your example code, the assignment operator wants to bind to a temporary, and temporaries cannot bind to non-constant references. By contrast, the copy constructor, which is invoked by the second piece of code, does accept a const reference, so there's no error.

Answer (score 1):

```
Matrix3D& Matrix3D::operator=(Matrix3D& m)
```

You request that the right-side parameter is an l-value. It must be an existing variable, cannot be a temporary value. Consider using `const Matrix3D& m` instead.

The `Matrix3D ret = rotX*rotY*rotZ;` works because it is not using `operator=` at all, instead it uses the default constructor `Matrix3D::Matrix3D(const Matrix3D&)`.