# the address of `*"space farers"` pointer to

Tags: c

I am following the "C Primer Plus" and encounter the following codes:

```
//strptr.c -- strings are pointers
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("%s, %p, %c\n", "We", "are", *"space farers");

    return 0;
}
```

Run it and come by:

```
./a.out
We, 0x1066e4fa1, s
```

Reference to the `*"space farers"`, the book explains that:

> *"space farers" should produce the value to which the address points, which should be the first character of the string "space farers".

Does it mean that `*"space farers"` is an address?
There's no pointers declared in the head?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under most circumstances, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.  The exceptions occur when the array expression is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration.

Thus, for any array

```
T arr[N];
```

the expression `arr` will "decay" to type "pointer to `T`", and the value will be the same as `&arr[0]`.

The *expression* `"space farers"` has type "13-element array of `char`".  Since it isn't the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, and it isn't being used to initialize a character array in a declaration, it "decays" to an expression of type `char *`, and the value of the expression is the address of the first element of the array.  Just as `*arr` is equivalent to `arr[0]`, `*"space farers"` is equivalent to `"space farers"[0]`, and gives us the *value* stored in the first element of the array - the character value `'s'`.

Comment: so any array  such as `{1, 2, 3}` is a pointer in its nature?

Comment: "space farers" is equivalent to {'s', 'p','a',...}, but *{'s','p','a',...} does not work.

Comment: @riderdragon:  No, arrays are not pointers; array *expressions* are converted to pointer expressions as necessary, but array *objects* are not pointers.  The brace notation only works in an initializer.

Answer (score 3):

`"space farers"` is a sequence of characters. C handles this by treating it as a pointer to the first character. This is why you see

```
char * str = "space farers";
```

`*xx` says 'return what this pointer xx points at'. For  `*"space farers"` thats the first character of the string, ie `s`.

A clearer way would be

```
 char * str = "space farers";
 char s = *str;
```

this removes the strange `*"...."` construct;

Comment: I would say this is incorrect by omission. A string literal is an array and C _may_ handle this  - _depending on context_ - by converting it to a pointer to the first element (character). See: https://godbolt.org/z/ckDEZK - if what you say in your answer was universally true, the static assertion would pass - but it fails instead.

Comment: For a rep 89 person I think we need to pitch the answer at the appropriate level

Comment: How does the 89 begin to explain it... more so than the title of the book?

Comment: regardless I think that adding a note saying "(this is a simplification which doesn't always apply)" would make the answer more correct and not make it less useful for beginners.

Answer (score 3):

`"space farers"` is a string literal - a string literal is an [*lvalue*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579421/often-used-seldom-defined-terms-lvalue) in C is of type `char [n]` where `n` is the number of characters in the literal plus one for the null terminator. In this case it is 13.

In almost all contexts an lvalue of array type decays to a pointer to the first element. Since the elements are of type `char`, the value after decay is of type `char *`.

The `*` dereferences the given pointer, which results to an lvalue of the element type - here of type `char`. This then is evaluated for its value - i.e. the value of the first character, which is integer `'s'` (115 if ASCII is the execution character).

---

TL;DR:

`*"space farers"` in itself is not an address, but an *lvalue* of type `char` that is the first character in the string. You can take an address of an *lvalue* with the `&` operator.

---

P.S. String literals, and string values are **not** pointers, but arrays.

Answer (score 0):

`"space farers"`is of type `char[]`. When passed to a function (`printf` in this case) it decays to `char*` and so `*"space farers"` is of type `char` and holds `'s'`.

Comment: `printf` has nothing to do with why `"space farers"` decays to `char *` here.

Comment: @trentcl It does in that `printf` is a function, so yes it has something to do with why.

Comment: sorry, I am trying to learn the tough topic. Is it char* or *char?

Comment: @riderdragon It's `char*`. `char*` says _a pointer to a `char`_. The syntax you mentioned is called dereferencing and that's used to get the value of what the pointer is pointing to.

Comment: `"space farers"` *isn't* passed to the function. It's the argument of the dereference operator `*`.