# Retrieve info about the &&x which keep the address of &x

Tags: c

I'd like to explore the feats of pointer with the following codes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int x = 3;
int main(void)
{
    printf("x's value is %d, x's address is %p", x, &x);
    //printf("x's address is stored in", &&x);
}
```

It works properly and get outputs

```
$ ./a.out
x's value is 3, x's address is 0x10b1a6018
```

When I utilize `&x`, a memory space is set aside for it to keep the address 0x10b1a6018, so an address is printed.

Sequently, I intent to get info about the address which store another address.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int x = 3;
int main(void)
{
    printf("x's value is %d, x's address is %p", x, &x);
    printf("x's address is stored in", &&x);
}
```

But it report error as:

```
$ cc first_c_program.c 
first_c_program.c:14:40: warning: data argument not used by format string [-Wformat-extra-args]
    printf("x's address is stored in", &&x);
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
first_c_program.c:14:42: error: use of undeclared label 'x'
    printf("x's address is stored in", &&x);
                                         ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

How could I retrieve information about the memory address which store the address of value x.

Comment: "When I utilize &x, a memory space is set aside for it " No, there is no memory reserved to store that address. It is only temporarily evaluated and passed to `printf`. This might be in a register. You cannot get the address of this value.

Comment: I love your comment "This might be in a register", cos, it should not be a ghost. @Gerhardh, could you please transmit it to answer.

Comment: I guess C standard should claim, variable as direct variable, pointer as indirect variable to eliminate the confusions for the newbie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&x`  is a non-lvalue expression. It does not have a location. `&` requires an [lvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579421/often-used-seldom-defined-terms-lvalue/52840265#52840265) as its operand (or a function).

`&&x` is not a valid construct at all in standard C. The address is not necessarily *stored anywhere at all* - in your program as `x` is a global variable, it is a compile/link-time constant!

---

Instead GCC uses unary `&&x` as an extension to get the *address of jump label x* for [computed goto](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html). This does not break C conformance by itself as `&&` is parsed as a *single token* and `&&` is not allowed as an unary operator in standard C.

I.e. you can write

```
    static void *array[] = { &&foo, &&bar, &&hack };

    int i = 1;
    goto *array[i]; // jump to label bar

    ...

foo: ...
bar: ...
baz: ...
```

Comment: literally, could I understand it as only the lvalue set aside a memory space?

Comment: @riderdragon No, &x gives you the address where x is stored. It already has an address whether you use &x or not.

Comment: @nos that's not exactly correct either (or at all), if we consider local variables etc.

Comment: @riderdragon Yes, but if you declare a variable `register`, it won't have an address either. It's weird that way.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala According to C it is, and the compilers that can optimize that away is an implementation detail.

Comment: @nos the C does not say that a variable has an address. It says it has a constant address in that 2 pointers to it compare equal.

Comment: "it is a compile/link-time constant!", but &x is a pointer, a pointer has its address itself rather a variable which does not not has an address itself compiled in symbol table.

Comment: If you count 2 + 3 mentally, and mark the result on paper, where did you store the 2?

Comment: If you see that the paper is on a table, where did you write that the paper is on the table?

Comment: @riderdragon A pointer is a variable that holds some address. `&x` yields a value which is the address of `x`. If you put this value into a pointer, you can take the address of that pointer similar to how you took the address of `x`.

Comment: I guess I got it now, pointer is a variable in its first place. @Swordfish

Comment: @ 1: i put the `2` in the 485,123th brain cell from the left. 2: i don't have to write down where the paper is as long as i can see it.

Comment: @Swordfish emphatically **no**. `&x` is an expression that has a pointer type.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala How does my sentence "`&x` yields a value which is the address of `x`" contradict or deny that this value has a type?

Comment: @riderdragon `&x` is a non-lvalue expression. It does not have an object whose address you could take.

Answer (score 5):

`&x` is a temporary value. It is not stored in memory and does not have an address.

Similarly `&42` is invalid because `42` is not stored in memory (it's also a temporary value).

The slightly weird error message you get is because gcc implements a unary `&&` operator, which can be used to get the address of a label. This is a non-standard extension of the C language.

To get a better error message, use `& &x` (with a space) or `&(&x)`.

But what you want simply doesn't exist.

Comment: much better now , `first_c_program.c:14:43: error: cannot take the address of an rvalue of type 'int *'`, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To do what you want, you need to store `&x` in a variable:

```
int* y = &x;
printf("%p", &y);
```